# Autocomplete field where title is replaced with NID

Tags: 7, theming, entities, forms, ajax

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have made autocomplete function to be called on a field.

File my_module.module:

```
<?php    

function my_module_menu() {
        
    $items = array();

    $items['/autocomplete'] = array(
        'title' => 'Autocomplete',
        'page callback' => 'companyAutocomplete',
        'access arguments' => array('autocomplete'),
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'weight' => 1,
        'file' => 'my_module.autocomplete.inc'
    );   
       
    return $items;
}
```

File my_module.autocomplete.inc:

```
<?php

function companyAutocomplete($fieldInput) {

    $returnArray = array();

    $query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        ->condition('n.title', '%'.db_like($fieldInput).'%', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('n.type', 'company', '=')
        ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
        ->range(0, 10);

    // print strtr((string) $query, $query->arguments());

    $results = $query->execute();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $returnArray[$result->title] = check_plain($result->title);
    }

    drupal_json_output($returnArray);
}
```

File template.php:

```
<?php

function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$vars) {

    if ($node = menu_get_object()) {

        if ($node->type == 'company') {

            if ($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_company') {
                $company = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $vars['items']['0']['#markup']);
                $vars['items']['0']['#markup'] = $company->label();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a field company (I use this field to enter NID):

```
$form['field_company'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $defaultCompany,
    '#title' => 'Company',
    '#autocomplete_path' => '/autocomplete',
);
```

When I type something in field, autocomplete returns correct text value of the searched term and that is ok.

How can I modify `companyAutocomplete()` function or the field itself for autocomplete to works as it is, but to write NID instead title in $form['field_company']['und'][0]['value']?

Answer (score 0):

You need the array keys to be nids, so change it to

```
$returnArray[$result->nid] = check_plain($result->title);
```

Comment: attention: showed up in LQP queue ...